# Installing Apache2 and PHP5 on a XServe G5 running 10.4

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx-server, php5, powerpc

I have an Apple XServe G5, running OS X Server 10.4. I want to update my Apache installation from 1.3 to 2 and PHP to 5. I also want to install PHP GD support. I have scoured the internet for a guide on how to do this, but to no avail. I also tried to use Entropy to install PHP 5 several times, and it always manages to royally mess up my system. Obviously I can't install Leopard or Snow Leopard because it is a PowerPC processor. Can anyone give me any tips on how to get this software updated or point me to a guide?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

1. You can install [MacOS X Server 10.5 Leopard on a XServe G5 PPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Server#Mac_OS_X_Server_10.5_.28Leopard_Server.29)
2. I used [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) to install my own Apache2 and PHP5 w/ GD2